# How to exclude unwanted JARs from exported WAR

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, maven-plugin

I'm using maven to build my Spring Dynamic Web Project. I got recommendations from my security team to remove certain JARs citing some sort of vulnerabilities. I have manually removed those JARs from by WEB-INF/lib/ everything is working for me.

But I would like to automatically remove those JARS at the time of exporting WAR file.

I've tried below

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar</warSourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

I tried `packagingExcludes` in the place of `warSourceExcludes` but no luck. And I tried the different version of maven-war-plugin.

Comment: If you don't need them don't add them as dependency to your project...

Comment: Or if the dependency is needed to compile then mark it as provided.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I'm not adding those libraries explicitly.

Comment: As @AndrewS stated if you don't need them mark them provided, even if it isn't an direct dependency you have. You could use an `dependencyManagement` block for that.

Comment: @AndrewS- In the dependency hierarchy of my Main project's pom.xml , I couldn't able to find those jars.  So I couldn't make out under which parent dependency I should mark is as provided.

Comment: Look at the dependency tree.  Note that randomly removing jars may work sometimes, but not all the time. They're a dependency for a reason.